# Downloading site images through terminal using curl

Tags: image, shell, curl, download

I'm trying to download a large batch of images from a website onto my Mac. I can download the smaller images with DownloadThemAll, SiteSucker, etc but they don't quite dig deep enough. So I've had to jump into Terminal which is a little bit out of my comfort zone and my skills are a bit rusty.

I've had a try with the script below:

```
curl -O http://www.domain.co.uk/system/images/[1-1000]/original/*.jpg
```

This script works and I can see the Terminal downloading the image files however the issue I'm having is that the files are being overwritten with *.jpg and not producing them sequentially such as 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg etc or even with their original names. The original jpg names use random numbers/letters (such as LIC0145_websource.jpg) which is why I've tried to supplement it with the *.jpg. I'm wondering which piece of code I'm missing to tell the Terminal to download these images.

I've also tired calling the shell script below but run into the 'Unexpected end of file'

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 1000`;
do
input=http://www.domain.co.uk/system/images/$i/original/*.jpg
output=$i.jpg
#   echo $input, $output
curl --output $output --remote-name $input
done
```

I think the curl option might still be a better option but if anyone has any fixes or other solutions let me know.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this with `wget` (I know that's not `curl`):

```
wget --no-parent --accept=jpg,jpeg,htm,html --mirror  http://somedomain/
```

Then CD to the directory and issue a

```
find ./ \( -iname '*.htm' -o -iname '*.html' \) -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When I ran the wget on the site it tried to mirror the site but didn't seem to grab the images from this directory http://www.domain.co.uk/system/images/$i/original/

The curl script from above worked but the issue I had was that I had to tell terminal not to call every file *.jpg and write over every jpg that was downloaded.